# How to remove text stamps from images?

Tags: python, opencv

I have picture like this:

[image]

It has text stamps randomly distributed throughout the image file. Some aspect to keep in mind about the image are;

- The text in the stamp is always same.
- No transparency.
- The text font is *black* thus there's some significant difference in contrast with original  text.

So my question is;

1. How do I find this text stamps? I'm guessing, maybe template matching with tolerance could help?
2. Although even if I found the exact location of the text, how do I get rid it? I could try to figure out the random background and do something like I've mentioned as follows;

   - Get the bounding box of the text stamp contour.
   - Then take all pixels outside of the contour.
   - Removing the contour and filling with random pixels from previous step and adding some blur should do the trick as I'm expecting.

Comment: you could try tesseract ocr to find "some" and after do some processing on it (blur or whatever)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code removes the stamp from your image:

```
inp_img = cv2.imread('stamp.jpg',cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
th,inp_img_thresh = cv2.threshold(255-inp_img,220,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
dilate = cv2.dilate(inp_img_thresh,np.ones((5,5),np.uint8))
canny = cv2.Canny(dilate,0,255)
_,contours,_ = 
cv2.findContours(canny,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
test_img = inp_img.copy()
for c in contours:
    (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    #print(x,y,w,h,test_img[y+h//2,x-w])
    test_img[y+3:y-2+h,x+3:x+w] = 240 #test_img[y+h//2,x-w]

cv2.imwrite("stamp_removed.jpg",test_img)
cv2.imshow("input image",inp_img)
cv2.imshow("threshold",inp_img_thresh)
cv2.imshow("output image",test_img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: Output Image With The Stamp Removed]